# Color the space between two\hrule

Tags: color, rules

This code is used to draw these two horizontal rules.

```
{ \color{red}\hrule width \hsize \kern 1mm }{\color{green}\hrule width \hsize height 1pt}
```

I need just to color the space between the rules. Any suggestion?

Comment: Which color should be applied to the space between the red and green rules?

Comment: @Mico, any color for example gray color

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 4):

`\hrule` is fairly unusual in that it is a vertical-mode macro. (Actually, it's a TeX "primitive" instruction rather than a macro built on one or more primitives.) As such, your code, *viz.*,

```
{\color{red}\hrule width \hsize \kern 1mm }{\color{green}\hrule width \hsize height 1pt}
```

is equivalent to

```
{\color{red}\hrule}\kern1mm{\color{green}\hrule height 1pt}
```

Because `\kern1mm` is sandwiched between two vertical-mode directives, it is also executed in vertical mode, i.e., it results in 1mm of *vertical whitespace* being inserted between the two rules (the upper one red, the lower one green). Aside: observe that `width \hsize` is redundant because the default width of the rule drawn `\hrule` *is* `\hsize` -- the width of the enclosing "vertical box".

To replace the vertical whitespace between the red and green rules with, say, a light-gray rule, it thus suffices to write

```
{\color{red}\hrule}%  % default height of \hrule is '0.4pt'
{\color{lightgray}\hrule height 1mm }% replacement for "\kern1mm"
{\color{green}\hrule height 1pt}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\setlength\textwidth{3cm} % just for this example
\begin{document}
% original expression
{\color{red}\hrule width \hsize \kern 1mm}{\color{green}\hrule width \hsize height 1pt}

\medskip
% modified, equivalent expression:
{\color{red}\hrule}%
\kern1mm%
{\color{green}\hrule height 1pt}

\medskip
% replace "\kern1mm" with "{\color{lightgray}\hrule height 1mm}"
{\color{red}\hrule}%
{\color{lightgray}\hrule height 1mm}%
{\color{green}\hrule height 1pt}
\end{document}
```